# scale bar figure - showing scale with citations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, citing

I am attempting to make figures similar to this:

[image]

[image]

with latex.

I would like for the citations to work in order to match the observed data from where it came.
Does anyone know of a good package or manner to do this?

The best I have been able to do is using Tikz, but the solution is pretty awful and I'm not very good at making it look decent.

The code below provides this image, which obviously needs a lot of work.
I am mainly interested in finding a package which makes this sort of thing more simplistic.

PDFLATEX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \foreach \i\s in {0.001/0,0.01/1,0.1/2,1/3} {
      \begin{scope}[xshift=\s cm]
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using log10(\x), evaluate=\x as \l using \x*\i] in {1,...,10} {
          \draw (\y,0) -- ++(0,.25) node [left, rotate=45] {\tiny \pgfmathprintnumber{\l} $\mu m$};
        }
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using log10(\x)] in {1,1.2,...,10} {
          \draw (\y,0) -- ++(0,.1);
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
     \draw (1cm+5, 0.3) -- (2cm+5, 0.3) node [above, rotate=0] {\tiny Micellular / Micro\cite{tadros2006applied}};
    %\draw (-.1,0) rectangle ++(3.2,.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Source & Micellular Emulsions - Microemulsions & Nanoemulsions & Macroemulsions \\
 \hline
 Tadros\cite{tadros2006applied} & 5-50 nm & 50-200 nm & $\ge50$ nm  \\ 
 \hline
 Binks\cite{binks1998modern} & 5-50 nm &  &  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

BIBTEX FILE:

```
@book{tadros2006applied,
title={Applied surfactants: principles and applications},
  author={Tadros, Tharwat F},
  year={2006},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
@book{binks1998modern,
  title={Modern aspects of emulsion science},
  author={Binks, Bernard P},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Royal Society of Chemistry}
}
```

Provides the following image:

[image]

Comment: A lot of people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a minimal working example.

Comment: As far as I understand the question chase wants to know to treat the citations in the figure and not how to draw the whole figure itself. But also there a bit more information are required: Are these stand-alone figures with stand-alone citations or must they integrate in a bigger document having the same shortcut, i.e. a), b) and c)? It would also be nice, if you could provide the corresponding BibTeX or BibLaTeX entries.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good starting point ...

```
\begin{filecontents}{Lit.bib}
@book{tadros2006applied,
    title={Applied surfactants: principles and applications},
    author={Tadros, Tharwat F},
    year={2006},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons},
}
@book{binks1998modern,
    title={Modern aspects of emulsion science},
    author={Binks, Bernard P},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Royal Society of Chemistry},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \setlist{itemsep=0ex plus0.2ex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        arrows.meta,
    }
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=none,
    style=numeric,
        ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Lit.bib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=5cm,
            xmin=1e0,
            xmax=5e4,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            %
            xlabel={nm},
            xlabel style={
                at={(current axis.right of origin)},
                anchor=north east,
                yshift=2ex,
            },
            %
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,   % <-- just for easier placement of lines
%            axis y line=none,  % <-- use me to hide the `axis y line'
        ]
            \begin{scope}[
                line width=2pt,
                node font=\scriptsize,
                >={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},
            ]
                \draw [->]
                    (axis direction cs:4,0.1) -- (axis direction cs:150,0.1)
                        node [above,pos=0,anchor=south west]
                            {Micellular / Micro \supercite{tadros2006applied}};
            \end{scope}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

        \vspace{2ex}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{28mm}p{28mm}p{28mm}}
            \toprule
        Source                               & \vspace*{-1.6ex}
                                               \begin{itemize}[label=--,leftmargin=*,nosep,]
                                                   \item Micellular \newline Emulsions
                                                   \item Microemulsions
                                               \end{itemize}
                                               \vspace*{-2.8ex} & Nanoemulsions & Macroemulsions \\
            \midrule
        Tadros \supercite{tadros2006applied} & 5--50 nm         & 50--200 nm    & $\ge50$ nm     \\
        Binks \supercite{binks1998modern}    & 5--50 nm         &               &                \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing result of above code]